# Regex - validate decimal number - max 50 digits excluding decimal | decimal optional | any no. of digits allowed before or after decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a regular expression that will validate a decimal number in such a way that

1. Any number of digits can be present before/after the decimal point.
2. Max length of the entire number is 50 (excluding decimal point).

> For eg. if 5 digits are present before the decimal then at most 45 digits can be
>   present after the decimal.

3. Decimal point is optional.

> A number of 50 digits is allowed without decimal point.

**For example, it should match these numbers:**

12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
12345.123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345

It would be great if anyone can help in this regard!

Comment: Java is not javascript. so which language

Comment: I have edited the tags.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be easy to find a regex that will match a number with a specified length.

Comment: @Andreas "should be easy to find a regex that will match a number with a specified length" - except that the validation is three fold. And limiting the total number of digits is not the only issue. Main problem I am facing is to dynamically check number of digits before decimal and after decimal. Meaning if before decimal 10 digits are present then automatically after decimal 40 digits should be allowed.

Comment: I have tried taking help from below two links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840723/regex-for-decimals-with-maximum-length  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274614/how-to-limit-the-number-of-digits-before-after-a-decimal-point-and-also-overall.

Comment: Right now this "question" is just a requirement which does not show any form of research - not even a simple regular expression that would recognize a string consisting only of numbers with a specific length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
^(?:\d{1,50}|(?=.{3,51}$)\d+\.\d+)$
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/xik69O/1)

```js
var test = [
    '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890', '12345.123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345',
    '123456.7890',
    '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901',
    '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.1'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^(?:\d{1,50}|(?=.{3,51}$)\d+\.\d+)$/.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: I think he wants a max length 50 not a min

Comment: @DanielE.: You're right, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex, which will match a whole number having digits anywhere from 1 to 50, or will match a decimal number having length 2 to 51, assuming `.2` is valid but `2.` is invalid.

```
^(?:\d{1,50}|(?=\d*\.\d+$)(?=.{2,51}$)[\d.]*)$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of string
- `(?:` --> Start of non-group
- `\d{1,50}` --> Matches a whole number of length 1 to 50
- `|` --> Alternation for separating decimal case
- `(?=\d*\.\d+$)` --> Ensures the number of form zero or more digits followed by a literal dot followed by one or more digits
- `(?=.{2,51}$)` --> Ensures the number of digits are anywhere from 2 to 51
- `[\d.]*` --> Actually captures the number
- `)` --> End of group
- `$` --> End of string

Here is a regex for 5-6 instead of 50-51 so you can easily play with it.

```
^(?:\d{1,5}|(?=\d*\.\d+$)(?=.{2,6}$)[\d.]*)$
```

**[Demo for max length 5-6](https://regex101.com/r/3b9zk6/1)**